# нахождение числа в диапазоне

Tags: python

Передо мной стоит задача найти числа из определенного диапазона в списке `TempPred`.

Мой код:

```py
O = (lambda x: 7000<x<30000, TempPred)
```

выдает:

```py
    ([[ 3172.19362974],
           [ 3810.48455547],
           [ 3184.33129711],
           [ 3349.42541508],
           [13293.07194055],
```

и т.д.

Comment: Что это за код? Что он делает? Чем он тебя не устраивает? Читай тут: [ask]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хм, если я правильно понял мысль:

```
TempPred = [
    [3172.19362974],
    [3810.48455547],
    [3184.33129711],
    [3349.42541508],
    [13293.07194055],
]

test = list(filter(lambda x: 7000 < x[0] < 30000, TempPred))
print(test)
```

Comment: мысль понята правильно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант через выражение генератор:

```
g = (x for x in TempPred if 7000 < x[0] < 30000)
print(list(g))
```

или через массив numpy:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(TempPred)
print(arr[(arr > 7000) & (arr < 30000)].tolist())
```